# Azure DevOps No Longer Showing in Visual Studio when Adding Project to Source Control

Tags: azure-devops, version-control, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

I recently updated Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.11.13. When I clicked **Add to Source Control** in the bottom right-hand corner, the option to publish the project to Azure DevOps in **Team Explorer --> Synchronization** no longer appeared. I've published Visual Studio projects to Azure DevOps this way for over 2 years now, and now I can't find a solution that works. Is there a setting that I'm missing that's not allowing me to publish to Azure DevOps?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps No Longer Showing in Visual Studio when Adding Project to Source Control

You could click the file and select clone repo:

[image]

we could add the new project to the local folder after we connect to the repo and clone the repo. Or we could copy the existing project to the local folder.

And you could do this from the team explorer.

Please check the document [Enhanced Productivity with Git in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/enhanced-productivity-with-git-in-visual-studio/) for some more deyails.